# How to change font size in radium

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to develop an ePub reader so I am evaluating different SDKs. How can I change font size and family in Readium SDK? Specifically in iOS project.

Is there any released app using Readium on AppStore?

Comment: how's your work progressing with readium? Do you recommend?

Comment: No, I can't recommend. There is more problems with Readium than font changing, anyway. I used AePubReader (https://github.com/fedefrappi/AePubReader) as a base for my application.

Comment: Have you get any update or solution on this... ?